# Mailchimp API Get last campaign sent

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is there any direct way to get the last campaign sent on a Mailchimp account via Mailchimp API V3?
So far the only way I found was to iterate over the campaigns and get the last one but it takes too much time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get only the last campaign sent using only one request, but you can achieve this by making two requests to the following endpoint

```
/campaigns
```

as described [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#read-get_campaigns). The parameters that you need are `count`, `status`, and `offset`.

For the first request, set the `count` parameter to 1 and `status` parameter to `sent`. You will get the first campaign sent, but you will also get `total_items` in the response body. The `total_items` indicates the total number of sent campaigns in your MailChimp account regardless of the pagination and that's what you need to make the second request.

For the second request, set the `count` parameter to 1, `status` parameter to `sent`, and `offset` parameter to the value of `total_items` above - 1. For example if the `total_items` from the first request is 150, then you should set `offset` to 149. Setting the `offset` parameter to 149 will skip the first 149 sent campaigns. The `campaigns` field in the response of the second request will contain the last campaign sent from your MailChimp account, which is what you're looking for. This will be much quicker than enumerating through all of the sent campaigns.

Comment: Great workaround! I manage to do it in a way similar to this. But this will be simpler to understand for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

```
/campaigns?sort_field=send_time&sort_dir=DESC&status=sent&count=1
```

Or for anyone who needs the last campaign from a particular folder:

```
/campaigns?folder_id=[FOLDER ID]&sort_field=send_time&sort_dir=DESC&status=sent&count=1
```

Comment: Just to add if anyone are trying to do this in Python: client.campaigns.all(sort_field="send_time", sort_dir="DESC", status="sent", count=1)